# Android Broadcast Receiver showing a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, broadcastreceiver

I've got an app that responds to an Alert - and I really need to show an alert with a password entry before going on to the next screen; the trouble is I don't seem to be able to show a dialog from a broadcast receiver -- so how can I show a dialog password entry upon receiving an alert?

Answer (score 7):

Create an activity, using `Theme.Dialog`, and call `startActivity()` to open it. While you cannot use a "real" `Dialog`, you can create a UI that looks like a `Dialog`.

Bear in mind that popping up an activity based on a broadcast may greatly irritate some users, who might not appreciate your dialog appearing in the middle of their game or text message conversation or whatever. You may wish to consider actually raising a `Notification`, then displaying the dialog when they open up that `Notification`.

Comment: Hey Mark - thanks for the info - I actually might flip to your wakelock code -- bought all your pdfs last week -- great books; just new to android. For this app it's kind of necessary so might be something the user agrees to...on top of this I'm running a dialog that runs a progbar with a 'while' thread that I'm having issues with - but I'll ask that in another question.  t

Comment: Could you consider accepting answers that actually answered your question, like this one, please?

Answer (score 0):

Go through the link below this is the complete example how to  make a custom dialog and call it automatically and gets pop up when the internet gets down hope it works for you

Click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41137562/4344659)

Answer (score 0):

You can't open Dialog from Receivers because it need ActivityContext

**Alternate way  You can open Acivity like dialog. Full example :**

1. MyReceiver.kt

   ```
    class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver {
      private val REMINDER_BUNDLE = "MyReminderBundle"

      override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val mIntent = Intent(context, DialogActivity::class.java)
        mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context?.startActivity(mIntent)
      }
    }
   ```
2. AndroidManife.xml

   `<activity android:name=".appview.settings.view.DialogActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"/>`
3. DialogActivity.kt

   ```
    class DialogActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog)
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true)

        //  create custom view of your dialog  in activity_dialog
        // or you can direct call alert dialog 
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: Please don't use x-large fonts to make your answer look weird.