# How to setup Alertbox from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, android-alarms

I have implemented alarm in android app. Alarm is working fine. `Toast` message is visible.
**Now I want to make Alert Box Notification to user**.

Here is code from `ReceiverActivity` Class. which I tried

```
public class ReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

// Code....


    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Alert Box")
    .setMessage("Msg for User")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // some coding...
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            arg0.dismiss();
    }
}).create().show();
}
```

}

Comment: whats the problem u r facing ?

Comment: Why do you need a dialog to pop up spontaneously (from the user's point of view)?  Why not use a Notification; that's what they're for.

Comment: @PSK I updated my answer for more details ..... read about it..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

---

*Although you can not show AlertDialog from Receivers because it needs ActivityContext.*

You have an alternate solution to show an Activity like AlertDialog from Receiver. This is possible.

To start Activity as dialog you should set theme of activity in manifest as `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />`

[Style Any Activity as an Alert Dialog in Android](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/623446/Style-Any-Activity-as-an-Alert-Dialog-in-Android)

---

To start Activity from Receiver use code like

```
    //Intent mIntent = new Intent();
    //mIntent.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.YourActivity"); 
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context,YourActivity.class) //Same as above two lines
    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(mIntent);
```

---

And one more reason behind not using AlertDialog from receiver (Even if you managed to show AlertDialog) is

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.
>
> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an
>   onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires
>   asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to
>   return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at
>   that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the
>   system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.
>
> In particular, ***you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from
>   within a BroadcastReceiver***. For the former, you should instead use the
>   NotificationManager API. For the latter, you can use
>   Context.startService() to send a command to the service. [More...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

So the better way is 'show notification' and alternate way is 'to use Activity as an Alert..'

***Happy coding :)***

Comment: It seems useful. let me try this. @Pankaj Kumar

Comment: can you explain me whats does setClassName() method do? @Pankaj Kumar

Comment: yes sure.. this is equivalent of `new Intent(context,YourActivity.class)` but here you need the full classname, including the package. You can use `new Intent(context,YourActivity.class)` too..

Comment: nice explanation.. @Pankaj Kumar

Comment: this type of Intent can call from BroadcastReceiver to launch Alert Box@Pankaj Kumar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29343/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-psk)

Comment: in my receiver method I put above code... when alert box popup then activity also open. but I don't need to open that activity. so is there any suggestion to do this?.. @Pankaj Kumar

Comment: how does whatsapp do it??

Answer (score 2):

You can try to show dialog with sytem alert attributes:

```
YourAlertDialog dialog = new YourAlertDialog(mContext);
dialog.getWindow()
        .setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
dialog.show();
```

And Add system alert permission in your mainfest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: what is AdShowDialog in this code, I am getting error on this. @buptcoder

Comment: Sorry, I forget change the name. I copied the code from my project.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot launch a popup dialog in your implementation of onReceive().**

further information check [AlertDialog from within BroadcastReceiver?? Can it be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844031/alertdialog-from-within-broadcastreceiver-can-it-be-done?rq=1)

Comment: Ok @Richa.. I am checking your link

Comment: how does whatsapp do it??

Answer (score 0):

I also looking for this solution but after searching lots of thing i did't get the exact ans for the custom dialog. So at this moment i make the `custom dialog` and pop up automatically when the internet connection gets down. So First of all we need to  make a custom layout which we used for pop up so here is my `alertforconnectioncheck.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/nonetwork1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:text="You are not connected to Internet!"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:drawablePadding="0dp"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                fbutton:cornerRadius="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
                fbutton:shadowHeight="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/ok_button"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="OK"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]
Now make the Broadcast extendable class:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String LOG_TAG = "NetworkChangeReceiver";
    public boolean isConnected = false;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    private Boolean status;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
        status = isNetworkAvailable(context);

        if (status == false) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertforconnectioncheck);
            dialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection...");
            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        if(!isConnected){
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Now you are connected to Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            isConnected = true;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "You are not connected to Internet!");
        Toast.makeText(context, "You are not connected to Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        isConnected = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now in MainActivity Class call the Broadcast Receiver class in `onCreate`:

```
private NetworkChangeReceiver receiver;
IntentFilter filter;
filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

This is the custom dialog box which appear automatically when the internet gets down and if you have a multiple `Activities` in the application you must be call it in every activity in the `onCreate` hope it helps for some one who looking for this  solution.

Comment: i am getting  exception android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application